# Group one column of dataframe by variable index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of PartialRoutes (which result together in full routes) and a treatment variable and I am trying to reduce the dataframe to the full routes by grouping these together and keeping the treatment variable.

To make this more clear, the df looks like

```
PartialRoute  Treatment
0             1
1             0
0             0
0             0
1             0
2             0
3             0
0             0
1             1
2             0
```

where every 0 in 'Partial Route' starts a new group, which means I always want to group all values until a new route starts/ a new 0 in index.
So in this example there exists 4 groups

```
PartialRoute  Treatment
0             1
1             0
-----------------
0             0
-----------------
0             0
1             0
2             0
3             0
-----------------
0             0
1             1
2             0
-----------------
```

and the result should look like

```
Route Treatment
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     1
```

Is there any solution to solve this elegant?

Comment: Can yo explain more? Why is last value `3` ? Why first `1`, next `0`, `0` ?

Comment: These are more or less bus routes which consists of different partial routes (e.g. first in bus line 1, then change to line 2 up to the destination). As there are different numbers of interchanges on the routes, the number of partial routes per route differs

Comment: hmm, so what are groups? still unclear for me, sorry.

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, every 0 starts a new group, but the lenght of the group differs, so thats why sometimes it goes up to 3 and sometimes the group is only one row (index 0)

Comment: can you add to question what are all groups from sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create groups by comparing by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then aggregate per groups, e.g. by `sum` or `max`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['PartialRoute'].eq(0).cumsum())['Treatment'].sum().reset_index()
print (df1)
   PartialRoute  Treatment
0             1          1
1             2          0
2             3          0
3             4          1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['PartialRoute'].eq(0).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    4
8    4
9    4
Name: PartialRoute, dtype: int32
```

If first value of `DataFrame` is not `0` get different groups - starting by `0`:

```
print (df)
   PartialRoute  Treatment
0             1          1
1             1          0
2             0          0
3             0          0
4             1          0
5             2          0
6             3          0
7             0          0
8             1          1
9             2          0

print (df['PartialRoute'].eq(0).cumsum())
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: PartialRoute, dtype: int32

df1 = df.groupby(df['PartialRoute'].eq(0).cumsum())['Treatment'].sum().reset_index()
print (df1)
   PartialRoute  Treatment
0             0          1
1             1          0
2             2          0
3             3          1
```